# Sprite Kit SKActions not firing

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit, skaction

I'm working on a project in Objective-C / Sprite Kit and cannot get Sprite Kit actions to work, I have tried everything I have seen but nothing has worked.

Here is some code:

myscene.h

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) SKAction *jumpAction;
@property (strong, nonatomic) SKAction *kneelAction;
@property (strong, nonatomic) SKAction *runAction;
```

myscene.m (init w/ size method)

```
[self setupCharacter];
[self createDpad];
[self spawnStartupClouds];
//self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVectorMake(0.2,-2);
self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVectorMake(0.2 ,-2);
self.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self;

[self setupActions];
```

myscene.m (setupActions method)

```
-(void) setupActions{
    SKTextureAtlas *jumpAtlas = [SKTextureAtlas atlasNamed:@"jump"];
    SKTexture *jumpTex1 = [jumpAtlas textureNamed:@"jump1.png"];
    SKTexture *jumpTex2 = [jumpAtlas textureNamed:@"jump2.png"];
    SKTexture *jumpTex3 = [jumpAtlas textureNamed:@"jump3.png"];

    NSArray *jumpAtlasTexture = @[jumpTex1, jumpTex2, jumpTex3];

    SKAction* jumpAtlasAnimation = [SKAction animateWithTextures:jumpAtlasTexture timePerFrame:0.1];
    SKAction* wait = [SKAction waitForDuration:0.5];


    jumpAction = [SKAction sequence:@[jumpAtlasAnimation, wait]];

    BBCharacter* leader = (BBCharacter*)[self childNodeWithName:@"character1"];

}


-(void)setupCharacter{
    NSLog(@"Setup character");
    leader = [BBCharacter node];
    leader.position = CGPointMake(100, 230);
    [self addChild:leader];

}
```

It also seems (in `setupActions`) it cannot "see" the `SKAction` `jumpAction`...

Comment: Try self.jumpAction instead of jumpAction.

Comment: This is a good video covering what you want https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6eAwWDje7ks

Comment: @michaelD33 my answer is helpful to you or not.

Answer (score 1):

When you declare a property in Objective-C in any class interface, you need to access it in the implementation using `self.propertyName`. You can also access the instance variable associated with that property by using `_propertyName`. So, the `jumpAction` property can be accessed using either `self.jumpAction` or simply `_jumpAction`.

This is because the property is not actually an instance variable, but an encapsulation over the class' data. Please have a look at the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/EncapsulatingData/EncapsulatingData.html) for a proper explanation.

Alternatively, to be able to access the property using it's exact name, you can explicitly synthesize it in the implementation.

```
@implementation MyScene //synthesize properties below this.

@synthesize jumpAction, kneelAction, runAction;
```

After doing so, you can access the properties directly, as you already do in your code.

A **suggestion**: You do not need to use properties for SKAction objects unless they need to be accessed by other classes.

Comment: There is no need to synthesize a property, this is done automatically. In this case the backing iVar has the property name prefixed with an underscore e.g _jumpAction.

Comment: Yeah, but if you want to use the exact name as the property, you will have to explicitly synthesize it.

Comment: Correct, i wanted to make clear that there is no need for an @synhtesize. For me your answer reads like you need one if you want to access the iVar directly what is just wrong.

Comment: Thanks, now that I have done this though, it says "local declaration of 'leader' hides instance variable" what do I do? Also I did run the project and nothing happened... It happens everytime I make edits, the character always just stays still.

Comment: have you called runaction on the leader node? Also, How have you declared it, and on which line does this warning show?

Answer (score 1):

hope this will help you

ok , By seeing your code i am able to understand that you have number images on your jump.atlas folder
and You want to animate your player to those texture when player jumps off .

so first of all add this line

```
[_playerNode runAction: jumpAction];
```

I am not seeing this line in your code.

Answer (score 0):

You have all the actions set up, now you just need to tell the node to perform the action with the runAction method.  If you are running the action then be most specific when you say you cannot get the actions to work.